# Вывод количества строк в файле

Tags: php

Дан файл text.txt, вот его содержимое:
 
1
 
2
 
3
 
4
 
5
 
6
 
7
 
8

Как мы видим, в нашем файле 8 строк. Необходимо, чтобы скрипт проверял содержимое файла text.txt и выводил текст, например: Файл text.txt содержит 8 строк. Заранее огромнейшие спасибо!

Comment: "Как мы видем это бутерброд, помогите мне пожалуйста опозназнать бутерброд, например это бутерброд."

лично для меня вопрос звучит примерно так же.

Comment: Надеюсь это поможет (остальное тоже почитайте)

http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl6_4.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr=file("file.txt");
echo count($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileData = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test.txt');
preg_matсh_all( "/\n/", $fileData, $lines );
echo 'Всего ' . count( $lines ) . ' строк';
===============================================
//ну или как вариант
$lines = explode( "\n", file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test.txt') );
echo 'Всего ' . count( $lines ) . ' строк';
```

Так или иначе приходится инициализировать массив так что сходу даже не скажу что будет быстрее..

Comment: Почему же "так или иначе приходится инициализировать массив"  ? ;)

Comment: и в первом и во втором случае выделяется память под `$lines`

Answer (score 1):

о, вроде понял что требуется :)

```
$cnt = 0;
$f = fopen('path/to/file.txt');
while (!foef($f)) {
    $cnt ++;
    fgets($f);
}
fclose($f);
```

или так. (без инициализации массива и загрузки файла в память)

Answer (score 0):

Вот, остальное сам додумывай:

```
$kolvo = explode("\n", $содержимое_файла);
$kolvo = sizeof($kolvo);
echo $kolvo; // Кол-во строк
```

Comment: Если уже запихали файл в память целиком, то число строк считайте через count().

Answer (score 0):

Источник

```
$arr=file("file.txt");
echo count($arr);
```

мой код

```
$arr=file("contact_data.csv");
<h4><?php echo count($arr);?></h4>
```

С помощью этого простого кода как указали выше можно решить я так решил можно тянуть инфу из любого файла например csv.
Спасибо за код.

Comment: _как указали выше_, где выше и кто указал?